# Nginx redirects http request to one vhost

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, 301-redirect

I have installed nginx with php-fpm.
When I try to access example.org it redirects me to https://example.com
What's wrong with my configs?

nginx.conf

```
    user  www;
    worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include vhosts/*.conf;
    }
```

example.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri; # enforce https
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    root /usr/local/www/example.com;
    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    ## Logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;

    ## SSL settings
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    location / {
        try_files $uri/ index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

example.org.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.org;
    root /usr/local/www/example.org;

    # logs
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.org_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.org_error.log;

    ## SSL settings
        ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4";
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 10m;
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    # Default location setting
    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        # Prevent Zero-day exploit
        try_files $uri =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess if Apache's doc. root
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Exclude favicon from logs
    location /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @Paul Yes, of course

Comment: I have nearly the exact 301 configuration on numerous sites and it works without issue. I have had other issues related to redirect server blocks that I was able to resolve by making access logs and error logs for each block.

Comment: Are you sure that it is Nginx that does the redirect?

Comment: @Pothi There is nothing but the nginx on that server.
However, When I rebooted server, the problem has gone.